# What is HTTP/REST protocol?

Tags: rest, http, protocols

*"MicroServices is an architectural style in which an application is developed as a number of loosely coupled services. Each service should be independently developed, deployed and tested. Services should communicate over a light weight protocol such as HTTP/REST."*

What does HTTP/REST mean in this text and what is the difference between HTTP/REST and HTTP?

Comment: Please mention the difference between protocols.

Answer (score 0):

It essentially means "HTTP, properly used".